# How to change the content type in exception handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mime-types

Suppose I have a controller that serves `GET` request and returns bean to be serialized to JSON and also provides an exception handler for `IllegalArgumentException` that can be raised in service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/meta/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public MetaInformation getMetaInformation(@PathVariable int itemId) {
    return myService.getMetaInformation(itemId);
}

@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    return ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
}
```

Message convertors are:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Now when I request the given URL in browser I see the correct JSON reply. However if exception is raised, the stringified exception is converted into JSON as well, but I would love it to be processed by `StringHttpMessageConverter` (resulting `text/plain` mime type). How can I go it?

To make the picture more complete (and complicated), suppose I also have the following handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/version", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getApplicationVersion() {
    return "1.0.12";
}
```

This handler allows the return string to be serialized by both `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `StringHttpMessageConverter` depending in passed `Accept-type` by the client. The return types and values should be as following:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| NN | URL                 | Accept-type           | Content-type     | Message converter                   |
|    |                     | request header        | response header  |                                     |
+----+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 1. | /version            | text/html; */*        | text/plain       | StringHttpMessageConverter          |
| 2. | /version            | application/json; */* | application/json | MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter |
| 3. | /meta/1             | text/html; */*        | application/json | MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter |
| 4. | /meta/1             | application/json; */* | application/json | MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter |
| 5. | /meta/0 (exception) | text/html; */*        | text/plain       | StringHttpMessageConverter          |
| 6. | /meta/0 (exception) | application/json; */* | text/plain       | StringHttpMessageConverter          |
+----+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I would like to note that you add or override _exisitng_ message converters. To completely replace default ones use "register-defaults=false" attribute.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20865

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think removing the `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` from `@RequestMapping` of the `getMetaInformation` will give you the desired result.

The response-type will be negotiated according to the content-type value in the Accept header.

---

*edit*

As this does not cover scenario 3,4 here is a solution working with `ResponseEntity.class` directly:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleIllegalArgumentException(Exception ex) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(ex.getMessage(), headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `ResponseEntity`! What about setting `supportedMediaTypes` property for `StringHttpMessageConverter` (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979543/267197))? Could be a solution as well.

Comment: I've just checked your solution with `ResponseEntity`: it does not work. The content type is overridden by message convertor, and message convertor is chosen (rough algorithms) by intersecting `Accept-type` and convertor's `supportedMediaTypes`.

Comment: I did test it successfully with Spring 3.1.2 on a tcServer v2.7. - Did you use the spring configuration mentioned in your question?

Comment: `ResponseEntity<String>`  and custom `HttpHeaders` worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

There are several aspects relating to the problem:

- `StringHttpMessageConverter` adds catch-all mime type `*/*` to the list of supported media types, while `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is bound to `application/json` only.
- When `@RequestMapping` is providing `produces = ...`, this value is stored in `HttpServletRequest` (see `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleMatch()`) and when the error handler is called, this mime type is automatically inherited and used.

The solution in simple case would be to put `StringHttpMessageConverter` first in the list:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <array>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN" />
                </array>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

and also remove `produces` from `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/meta/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MetaInformation getMetaInformation(@PathVariable int itemId) {
    return myService.getMetaInformation(itemId);
}
```

Now:

- `StringHttpMessageConverter` will discard all types, which only `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` can handle (`MetaInformation`, `java.util.Collection`, etc) allowing them to be passed further.
- In case of exception in scenario (5, 6) `StringHttpMessageConverter` will take the precedence.

So far so good, but unfortunately things get more complicated with [`ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter.java). For handler return type `java.util.Collection<MetaInformation>` this message convertor will report that it can convert this type to `java.lang.String`. The limitation comes from the fact that collection element types are erased and `AbstractHttpMessageConverter.canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType)` method gets `java.util.Collection<?>` class for check, however when it comes to conversion step `ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter` fails. To solve the problem we keep `produces` for `@RequestMapping` annotation where JSON convertor should be used, but to force correct content type for exception handler, we will erase `HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE` attribute from `HttpServletRequest`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleIllegalArgumentException(HttpServletRequest request, IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    request.removeAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);
    return ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/meta", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Collection<MetaInformation> getMetaInformations() {
    return myService.getMetaInformations();
}
```

Context stays the same as it was originally:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="conversionService">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
            </property>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <array>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN" />
                </array>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Now scenarios (1,2,3,4) are handled correctly because of content-type negotiation, and scenarios (5,6) are processed in exception handler.

Alternatively one can replace collection return type with arrays, then solution #1 is applicable again:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/meta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MetaInformation[] getMetaInformations() {
    return myService.getMetaInformations().toArray();
}
```

---

For discussion:

I think that `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters()` should not inherit class from value, but rather from method signature:

`Type returnValueType = returnType.getGenericParameterType();`

and `HttpMessageConverter.canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType)` should be changed to:

`canWrite(Type returnType, MediaType mediaType)`

or (in case it is too limiting potential class-based convertors) to

`canWrite(Class<?> valueClazz, Type returnType, MediaType mediaType)`

Then parametrized types could be handled correctly and solution #1 would be applicable again.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer that worked for me. Specifically the line `request.removeAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);` or by extension `request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE, Collections.singleton(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`