# MVC Interceptor get content type of Exception handler method

Tags: spring-mvc

If I have a method such as the following in a Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mymapping",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public final JsonResponse<?> myMethod() {
```

When the method throws an exception, I want a MVC interceptor to catch it and return a JSON error.  I only want this to work for `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` methods in the controller.

How can I do this in my `afterCompletion` of `HandlerInterceptor`.  If I inspect the contentType of the response it is null when an exception occurs.

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Instead of an interceptor, you might want to try `@ControllerAdvice` with an `@ExceptionHandler` method(s). See this other SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16313685/1174467

Comment: Also see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977368/how-to-change-the-content-type-in-exception-handler

Comment: @superEb this will cause all `@ExceptionHandler` to be called for all mappings regardless of their content type. (XML and Json will return a JsonResponse).  I only want methods that produce json be processed by the exception handler.

Comment: Can you check the `Accept` header of the request in your interceptor method instead? Maybe populate a custom request attribute before re/throwing the exception in controller method? Can you apply a different interceptor to controllers that produce different data formats? Sorry, it seems like there are multiple ways to address this, but probably not the *exact* way you're looking for.