Quarkus REST Streaming - How to return error when stream crashes?
i need to create a CSV-Export that streams data (not load it completely into memory):
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/export/csv")
    public Response streamCsv() throws InvalidDataException {
        final StreamingOutput streamingOutput =
            os -> productManager.exportCsv(new RequestContext(1, 1), os);
        return Response
            .ok(streamingOutput, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=product_export.csv")
            .build();
    }

this works correctly,
but when the stream crashes (because of any type of error during the stream-processing) the endpoint will still return a HTTP Status-Code 200 (Success), and will not return an error to the caller (like HTTP Status-Code 500)
The caller will get the impression that the CSV-File is valid, but it may only contain as many lines until the error occured.

How can i write a streaming-endpoint in quarkus, that can return Error-Codes to the Caller to indicate if the streaming had an error ?

Note: it is important to note, that the full data should not! be loaded into memory at any time. It is allowed to load small chunks of data into memory. Therefore a solution that contains os.toByteArray() would not be sufficient.

Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62479144/17547033

I got it to somehow work like i would expect it to work.

given that the HTTP-Header (and Status-Code) is already written with 200 (OK) as soon as we start to write the body (this is HTTP specific, and not quarkus-specific)

we could cut the request-connection, so the client will get at least some kind of information (aborted connection) that an error has occured.

Quarkus seems to work with Vertx under the hood.
The HttpServerResponseOutputStream is just a helper-class to wrap the response.write() calls into an OutputStream and not relevant for the example.
it is expected that all writers finish non-gracefully when an error occurs to make sure a "defect" file is produced in that case, so that even clients ignoring the "Aborted Connection" error would not be able to open the file.

the Status-Code 200 is still contained within the aborted request, so the client must be aware that connections are aborted.


Thread.sleep is needed after connection.close, because sometimes the server is faster with sending out the response before the close has taken place. That way we can make sure (in a hacky way) that it is closed before the response is finally processed.

I would still wait and hope for a better solution...
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/export/xlsx")
    public void streamXlsx(@Context HttpServerRequest request, @Context HttpServerResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setChunked(true); // Enable chunked responses
            response.putHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            response.putHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=product_export.xlsx");

            productManager.exportXlsx(new RequestContext(1, 1), new HttpServerResponseOutputStream(response));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.write("ERROR DURING PROCESSING!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                //
            }
            request.connection().close();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                //
            }
        }
    }

